# Problems in adding data to the database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My problem is to add data to the database by taking the information from a form.
I want to add the information as "name". I can add "email" correctly but not other data.

My code:

```js
buttonsignup.addEventListener('click', error => {
  var nameCompany = document.getElementById('nameCompany').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
});

function add(nameCompany,email) {
    firebase.database().ref().child('users_company').push({
        nameCompany: nameCompany,
        email: email
    });
}


function intFirebase () {

    /*CURRENT USER*/
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user != null) {
            console.log(user);
            console.log('El UID es '+user.uid);
            add(nameCompany,user.email);
        } else {
            console.log('No user is signed in.');
        }
    });
}

window.onload = function() {
    intFirebase();
}
```

Okay, After turning the coffee into code. I found this solution. But ... Is it a good practice?

```js
const database = firebase.database();
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

/* BOTON SIGNUP */

buttonsignup.addEventListener('click', error => {

 var nameCompany = document.getElementById('nameCompany').value;
 var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
 var password_1 = document.getElementById('password_1').value;
 var password_2 = document.getElementById('password_2').value;
 
 if (password_1 == password_2) {
  if (password_1.length < 8) {
   console.log('Contraseña muy corta');
   document.getElementById("errorPassword").innerHTML = "8 characters";
  } else {
   firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password_1).then (function(result) {
    add(nameCompany,email);
   }).catch(function (error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    };
   });
  }
 } else{
  console.log('errorPassword');
 }
});

function add(nameCompany,email) {
 firebase.database().ref().child('users_company').push({
  nameCompany: nameCompany,
  emailCompany: email
 });
}


function intFirebase () {

 /*CURRENT USER*/
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user != null) {
   console.log(user);
   console.log('El UID es '+user.uid);
  } else {
   console.log('No user is signed in.');
  }
 });
}

window.onload = function() {
 intFirebase();
}
```

And database rules

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "users_company": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": true,
          //Change this code to: I can not do scripts in the database. -> ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid === $uid",
        "nameCompany" : {
         ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
        },
        "emailCompany" :{
         ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific (professional) in your question title. Not "the database", but "a Firebase database". While you have firebase in your list of tags, that isn't good enough. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

In your intFirebase function you are only calling your database if there is a current user already logged in. The reason your email is working, is only because you are using 'user.email,' after it sees that a user is indeed logged in.

If you are trying to create a new user (which I think that is what your event listener at the top is trying to do), then you should move your add function to fire off when you submit the form.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Yes, I am trying to register users. Inside the form there is "name, email and password".

I'll try your solution. I will come with comments and if I can solve it, I will return with the solution.